# DynamoDB Local - Connection Refused from PHP

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am running DynamoDB Local on port 8080. This is the command used to start the DB:

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -port 8080
```

Going to `localhost:8080/shell/` yields the DynamoDB Javascript Shell. The shell  works and allows operations to be performed on a local db file. The db file created by using the shell is named `cUniqueSessionID_us-west-2.db`.

In a PHP project, I have the following code for creating a table using DynamoDB

```
$db = new \Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient([
    'region'   => 'us-west-2',
    'version'  => 'latest',
    'endpoint' => 'http://localhost:8080/',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'not-a-real-key',
        'secret' => 'not-a-real-secret',
    ],
]);
$db->createTable([
    'TableName' =>'SampleTable',
    'AttributeDefinitions' => [
        [ 'AttributeName' => 'Id', 'AttributeType' => 'N' ]
    ],
    'KeySchema' => [
        [ 'AttributeName' => 'Id', 'KeyType' => 'HASH' ]
    ],
    'ProvisionedThroughput' => [
        'ReadCapacityUnits'    => 5,
        'WriteCapacityUnits' => 6
    ]
]);
```

But running this yields `Error executing "CreateTable" on "http://localhost:8080/"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused`

I've tried turning off my firewall without success. What could be causing this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the issue.

My PHP project is running in a Vagrant virtual machine, but I was running DynamoDB on my local machine. Thus, the `localhost` in my PHP code refered to the *vagrant localhost* but DynamoDB was running on my *machine's localhost*.

To solve the problem, I ran DynamoDB from within Vagrant.