# Set Up Laravel And DynamoDB Locally On Laravel Homestead?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have installed the AWS SDK for PHP, I have created an IAM user on my AWS account with access keys and I a have downloaded and installed NoSQL Workbench for DynamoDb. I have configured my local access keys. I have also created a table in NoSQL Workbench called smash. When I run the following command in my terminal:

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

I get the following:

```
{
    "TableNames": []
}
```

Which doesn't look right? What steps do I need to take to install and use dynamodb locally?

I am running my project in a Laravel 9 site within Laravel Homestead.

Comment: What does this have to do with Laravel? Looks like a database configuration question, which is potentially off-topic here.

Comment: When you created the table using NoSQL Workbench, was its database connection set to localhost:8000?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say for sure just from the details in the question, but my intuition is that what you did is you’ve created the table called ‘smash’ in your AWS account and not in you local DynamoDB instance.

DynamoDB local doesn’t have anything to do at all with your AWS account. You can download and run that locally even if you don’t have an AWS account at all.

If it is local development that you’re trying to do, focus on that aspect.

Comment: I did some digging and found that I was making calls to my local computer, but my project was running inside of Laravel Homestead, a local dev vagrant box? So I couldn't make any calls properly. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131363/dynamodb-local-connection-refused-from-php). I am getting the exact same error. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: In this case, you have two options: (I) you can run the DDB local inside the Vagrant VM, or (II) you can change the Vagrant VM networking to use NAT and expose the host network to it; then make sure the DDB local is listening on an IP address on your host network